# Set a rule depending on a data prop on a vueJS form input

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js

I took a look at this page: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs

I saw it was possible to customize rules, for example:

```
  rules: [
    value => !!value || 'Required.',
    value => (value || '').length <= 20 || 'Max 20 characters',
    value => {
      const pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      return pattern.test(value) || 'Invalid e-mail.'
    },
  ],
```

However, I was wondering if it was possible to customize a rule depending on a component prop, for example:

```
value => (value || '').length <= this.maxLength || 'Max ' + this.maxLength + ' characters'
```

My example above doesn't work, of course.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The mistakes that you were making

- `rules` should be a computed property, since it can change
- you should call it with parent component and pass prop `maxLength`

Here's a working example for you, where `Validation` is the component implementing `rules` and `App` is the parent component calling it with prop `maxLength`: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-thunder-mvl6o.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work when I want a cross validation: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-river-7wh6d